# Kubuntu 12.10 cannot be installed alongside Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7, kubuntu

I would like to install Kubuntu alongside Windows 7, but installer does not see my previous installation.

I have extra 25 GB disk space free unallocated for Kubuntu.

I installed boot-repair while using LiveCD and here is its output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1644214/

I tried Ubuntu installation and it saw Windows 7. I do not have UEFI enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Install Ubuntu first, then "upgrade" Ubuntu to Kubuntu by typing `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.
2. Install Wubi instead of a main ISO.

Comment: Will the first solution remove GNOME as well and will everything be Kubuntu including default software?

Comment: First question: Please type `sudo apt-get --purge remove unity` and second question: yes.

Comment: Yes, it succeeded using Wubi thanks, but did not try first one...